# Unique root for a simple convolution

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convolution, gaussian-integral

I am struggling to show the following problem. Let $f \in \mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ (satisfying the exponential growth condition) be a real function and $x^*\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is strictly positive before $x^*$, strictly negative after. Formally,

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x) > 0 \text{ if } x<x^*, f(x) <0\text{ if } x>x^*.$$

More generally, we suppose $f$ changes sign only once.

**Can one show that the the function $g$ defined as :**

$$g(x) := \int_\mathbb{R}f(x+s)e^{-s^2/2}ds$$

**has a unique root on $\mathbb{R}$** ?

I am pretty sure that it is true. Any hints, solutions or even counter-examples would be highly appreciated ! Thank you very much. (I am not familiar with the properties of the convolutions.)

If the statement is false, could you provide some stronger conditions on $f$ that makes it true ?

### Examples

If $f(x) = -x$, then $g(x) = -x$ and the result holds. If $f = \arctan$, the figure shows that the claim still holds:
[image]

With more complex function (non-increasing) such as :

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x^2}$$

we have:

[image]

Comment: There might be a problem of integrability if $f$ is only $\mathcal{C}^\infty$.

Comment: Absolutely right, I updated the post by adding the exponential growth condition.

Comment: I'm guessing there is a reason why you believe your claim is true, maybe you could give an example or two in your post? That might help other users in looking for a solution or for a counterexample. It's an interesting question especially if the claim is proven true.

Comment: I updated the post and added two examples.

Comment: We have that $g$ is positive in $-\infty$ and negative in $\infty$. Since $g$ is continuous, we have to prove the uniqueness of the root.

Comment: This is a consequence of the "total positivity" of the bilateral Laplace transform.

Comment: Thank you @kimchilover, however, I am absolutely not familiar with the Laplace transform, could you give me more details about what you mean by this property of "total positivity" ?

Comment: Furthermore, I don't see the link with the bilateral Laplace transform since I use a gaussian kernel.